# Most efficient way of comparing long arrays of strings

Tags: android

I'm using the speech recognizer to get a voice input from the user, it returns an array of 5 strings which I pass to this method

```
    public int analyzeTag(ArrayList<String> voiceResults,Editor editor, Context context){
            for (String match : voiceResults) {
                Log.d(TAG, match);
                if (match.equalsIgnoreCase(context.getResources().getString(R.string.first_tag))){
                    editor.append(context.getResources().getString(R.string.first_tag));
                    return 1;
                }
                else if (match.equalsIgnoreCase(context.getResources().getString(R.string.second_tag))){
                    editor.append(context.getResources().getString(R.string.second_tag));
                    return 1;
                }
                //etc....(huge list of tags)
                //Some tags might also have acceptable variations, example:
                else if (match.equalsIgnoreCase("img") || match.equalsIgnoreCase("image")
                {
                     editor.append("img"); //the string to append is always taken from the first variation
                }

            }
            return 0;
        }
```

This method compares the results with a list of tags, the tag list will be pretty big with hundreds of tags so I would like to find the most efficient way to do this operation.

I need help with:

**1**.Is my way of comparing results the most efficient? Is there a better way? (from the user experience perspective, I don't want users waiting a long time to get a result).
The voice input will be a big part of my app so this method will be called quite often

**2**.I have a long list of tags, obviously the if(), elseIf() route is gonna be quite repetitive, is there a way to iterate this? Considering the fact that some tags might have variations (even more than 1)and that the variation 1 ("img") will be the same for everyone, but other variations will be locale/language sensitive example: "image" for english users "immagini" for italian users etc.
Text appended to the editor will be always taken from the first variation

Comment: Detecting cases which are way off and not taking these cases into consideration may help in increasing some efficiency. 
How about using String.Contains(VoiCeString,Major_Word_From_TriggerString), before using the comparison for this. Even comparing their lengths to knock out mismatching cases may be handy.

Comment: your way is absolutely inefficient. First, don't store every string in separate resource string, use String array resource instead: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray Second, when your app launches, collect all strings to `HashSet` collection and use its `contains()` method to discover if the given string presents in the set.

Comment: @Eu.Dr. I will select the already given answer as accepted and I'll include the code I've used in the end as another answer so it will be helpful to others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about puting tags in a StringArray and then iterate though the array ?

```
  String[] tags = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tags);
    for (String match : voiceResults) {
        for (int index = 0; index < tags.length; index++ ) {            
            if (match.equalsIgnoreCase(tags[index]) {
                editor.append(tags[index]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the [doc on StringArray](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray)

Comment: But this method would not work in case i have some variations (see the code where I've put the comments).
Also keep in mind that the variations will be locale sensitive